# Angular 2 gives issue while ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli, mean-stack

Angular 2 gives issue while doing ng serve and gives issue in angular-src/node_modules/@types/lodesh/common/object.d.ts

I am not able to find what exactly is the issue with this.

Comment: lodash does not require @types, remove the node_modules and run npm install again

Comment: @Ricardo this does not seem to work

Comment: We could help you more, if you gave us a [complete question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ricardo, after trying the solution one more time it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @MikeTung Issue just got solve.